# error in the pom file netbeans 8

Tags: netbeans-8

I have this error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project weka-dev: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Following is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
<artifactId>weka-dev</artifactId>
<version>3.7.14-SNAPSHOT</version><!-- weka-version -->
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>weka-dev</name>
<description>The Waikato Environment for Knowledge Analysis (WEKA), a machine 
    learning workbench. This version represents the developer version, the
    "bleeding edge" of development, you could say. New functionality gets added
    to this version.
</description>
<url>http://www.cms.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/</url>
<organization>
    <name>University of Waikato, Hamilton, NZ</name>
    <url>http://www.waikato.ac.nz/</url>
</organization>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>GNU General Public License 3</name>
        <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>wekateam</id>
        <name>The WEKA Team</name>
        <email>wekalist@list.waikato.ac.nz</email>
    </developer>
</developers>

<mailingLists>
    <mailingList>
        <name>wekalist</name>
        <subscribe>https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist</subscribe>
        <unsubscribe>https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist</unsubscribe>
        <archive>https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/htdig/wekalist/</archive>
    </mailingList>
</mailingLists>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
</parent>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka</developerConnection>
    <url>https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka</url>
</scm>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>performRelease</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- used for skipping tests -->
        <id>no-tests</id>
        <properties>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka.thirdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-cup-11b</artifactId>
        <version>2015.03.26</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka.thirdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-cup-11b-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2015.03.26</version>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka.thirdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>bounce</artifactId>
        <version>0.18</version>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <weka.main.class>weka.gui.GUIChooser</weka.main.class>
</properties>

<build>
    <directory>dist</directory>
    <outputDirectory>build/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>build/testcases</testOutputDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
            <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.arff</include>
                <include>**/*.cost</include>
                <include>**/*.cup</include>
                <include>**/*.default</include>
                <include>**/*.excludes</include>
                <include>**/*.flex</include>
                <include>**/*.gif</include>
                <include>**/*.icns</include>
                <include>**/*.ico</include>
                <include>**/*.jflex</include>
                <include>**/*.jpeg</include>
                <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                <include>**/*.kfml</include>
                <include>**/*.matrix</include>
                <include>**/*.png</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.props</include>
                <include>**/*.txt</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/DatabaseUtils.props.*</include>
                <include>weka/gui/beans/README</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</targetPath>
            <directory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.arff</include>
                <include>**/*.cost</include>
                <include>**/*.cup</include>
                <include>**/*.default</include>
                <include>**/*.excludes</include>
                <include>**/*.flex</include>
                <include>**/*.gif</include>
                <include>**/*.icns</include>
                <include>**/*.ico</include>
                <include>**/*.jflex</include>
                <include>**/*.jpeg</include>
                <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                <include>**/*.kfml</include>
                <include>**/*.matrix</include>
                <include>**/*.png</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.props</include>
                <include>**/*.txt</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/DatabaseUtils.props.*</include>
                <include>weka/gui/beans/README</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <weka.test.Regression.root>src/test/resources/wekarefs</weka.test.Regression.root>
                        <weka.test.maventest>true</weka.test.maventest>
                        <user.timezone>Pacific/Auckland</user.timezone>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/tags</tagBase>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <!-- tests are performed with the ant build file, hence skipped here. -->
                    <preparationGoals>clean verify -P no-tests</preparationGoals>
                    <goals>deploy -P no-tests</goals> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>.</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*~</include>
                            <include>**/.attach_pid*</include>
                            <include>**/hs_err_pid*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
  

        
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${weka.main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeResources>true</excludeResources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-test-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <maxmemory>256m</maxmemory>
                <subpackages>weka:org</subpackages>
                <show>public</show>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/doc</outputDirectory>
                <!-- when using Java 8, use this setting to avoid overly strict javadoclet -->
                <!--additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam-->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
   
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: You should edit your question. First you should see that you have the right formating (All code should be displayed as code). Then you should see, if your code fullfills the definition of a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and lastly you should include some details of *what yoh have tried to do*

Comment: You 're trying to run Weka. try deleting the old plugin for org.codehaus.mojo. Make sure the execution command is as follow: "mvn clean install". Appearently your pom file does not state the mojo plugin. Use this:
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
</plugin>